# OKTA API Token life span

Tags: date

I have created a token last year on May 3rd 2016 and its expiration date is on June 22nd 2017.

The recently created token (on May 11th 2017) its expiration date is June 28th 2017, if this tokens lifetime is 30 days then the expiration date in OKTA should get displayed as June 10th 2017.

Please let me know why the expiration date for the last years token (which was created on May 3rd 2016) is getting displayed as June 22nd 2017.

Also let me know why the expiration date for token created on May 11th 2017 is getting displayed as June 28th 2017 instead of June 10th 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okta's API tokens get refreshed with every API call made.

[Getting a Token documentation](https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/getting_started/getting_a_token.html#token-expiration):

> Okta uses a bearer token for API authentication with a sliding scale expiration. Tokens are valid for 30 days and automatically refresh with each API call. Tokens that are not used for 30 days will expire. The token lifetime is currently fixed and cannot be changed for your organization.

Your expiration date will always be **30 days** after your last API call.

Comment: Hello @jmelberg, Will the refresh token on Okta expired?
I have never seen it changed every time I make a refresh. If the anwer is yes, how can I refresh the refresh token without force user to relogin ?